# Tray application in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, trayicon

I am new in C# .NET in WPF and I am trying to make a basic application based as tray icon and so using no windows.

As tray application I mean one in the following picture:

[image]

Creating a new VisualStudio project I see following "default" libraries, some of these are used to manage windows. This default project is a window base application.

[image]

Which libraries I have to use for a tray based application?

Can you give me a basic and working example on which I can start?

Comment: WPF or Windows Forms? See  [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290013/Formless-System-Tray-Application) for the former and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290013/Formless-System-Tray-Application) for the latter..

Comment: You can start with a simple WinForms template and the remove Form1.

Comment: I am on WPF, description updated.

Comment: For a Tray (-only) app it makes little difference... I think the startup code for WinForms gives you a better grip.